# Are the verbs that are conjugated to end in "-n" in the past participle related?

Tags: verbs, history, past-participles, morphology, inflectional-morphology

There are many words that in English are conjugated in the past participle to end in "-n": *grow* goes to *grown*, *sew* goes to *sewn*, *throw* goes to *thrown*, etc..   I'm guessing it was probably the regular ending in English in some long-past time.   But as every growing child knows, the more common form has become conjugating the past tense to end in "-ed": *jog* goes to *jogged*, *flog* goes to *flogged*, *clog* goes to *clogged*, and so on.  Even completely foreign words are usually regularized in English to have their past tense end in "-ed"; *abet* goes to *abetted*, *blink* goes to *blinked*.

I was wondering two things: Did all the words that are conjugated to end in "-n" in the past tense come from a shared language family, or was it a "regularization" procedure as well back when it was more common?  Did something precipitate the change from "-n" to "-ed", like a conquest, or some other notable historical event?

Comment: A correction: the forms that you mention in *-n* are not the past tense forms, but the past participle. I've added this tag to your question. It's a good question, BTW, but I don't have time to answer at the moment :(.

Comment: Ah, the good olden days...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a simple question, which actually requires a quite complex answer (which I've made as simple as I can). This is because there are several phenomena at work here.

1. English is of West Germanic descent, as you well know, and beyond this descends from Proto-Indo-European.
2. Old Germanic has 2 classes of verbs, **strong verbs** and **weak verbs**, which are differentiated by the way they form their past tenses.
   Don't ask me why they are named like this; those weak/strong names come from a German guy called [Jacob Grimm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Grimm). 
   Being German, he called the phenomenon of changing stem vowels in inflections "[ablaut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_ablaut)".  More broadly, vowel changes like this are common in Indo-European languages and not restricted to verbs (*man* => *men*; *Man* => *Männer*; *homō* => *homin-ēs*).
   Here are a few examples for German verbs (using modern forms for the sake of clarity).

   - The [weak verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_weak_verb)
     are the ones that keep their stem unchanged and add a dental ( a 'd' or
     a 't') at the end. For instance:
     *lieben* (to love) => *Ich liebte* (I loved) => *geliebt* (loved).
     Old Germanic and Old English had four classes of weak verbs, depending on morphological rules.
   - The [strong verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_strong_verb) don't do that at all.  Instead they change the last vowel in their root.
     For instance:
     *singen* (to sing) => *Ich sang* (I sang) => *gesungen* (sung)
     Old English and Old Germanic had seven classes of strong verbs depending on the rules used to build the past tenses.
     But *look how similar the German and English vowels actually are*.
     This is in fact a general rule: if you know your German strong verbs, learning the English irregular verbs is much easier
     (or the other way round if you're learning German).
     So these are the verbs that are more likely to end with an "-n" in English.
3. The origin of the weak dental suffix is the Old Germanic suffix "ōdaz".
   In Old English it gradually transformed in "-ode" (or "-ade" or "ede" depending on the dialects"). In Old Germanic, this "oda" can be considered as an ancestor to "did" so that to say "I loved", you would actually say "I love did".
4. After the migration to Britain,
   German and English followed separate
   evolution paths.    and the "odaz"
   was transformed in the German "-te" on
   the eastern side of the English
   channel and "-ed" on the western side
   (for the preterite).
5. Another phenomenon has to be taken into account.  [Irregular verbs tend to disappear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_irregular_verbs).
   The less commonly used the quicker their "regularisation".  This is because of "incomplete grammatical education" when old morphological rules are supposed to be passed on to newer generations.
6. All recent verbs are regular and
   there are in English a number of
   irregular verbs that are currently
   in that process of becoming regular.
   You can observe
   that they admit both a regular and
   an irregular past tense: *strived*
   instead of *strove* is a well known
   example.

Comment: Note that the vowel changes in _man/men_ and _homō/hominēs_ are completely unrelated to ablaut. The Germanic one is _umlaut_, the influence of an original /i/ in the following syllable. In Proto-Germanic, there was no vowel change here at all (the plural was _*manniz_). The Latin one is just a simple case of vowel reduction: most vowels get reduced to /i/ in Latin in internal, unaccented, open syllables.

Answer (score 12):

So, the difference you note started in Old English, which had the concept of strong and weak verbs.  Strong verbs marked their past and past participles by varying the vowel sound in the base of the word (e.g. *swim/swam/swum* in Modern English).  Weak verbs used a suffix (*-d* or *-t* if I recall correctly, *feel*->*felt* is a modern example).  Through Middle English, new verbs that were added used the weak verb paradigm and this approach became the foundation for what we know as 'regular verbs' now.

One class of the strong verbs maintained the vowel shift only (*sing/sung*, *drink/drunk*, *ring/rung*).  A second class of strong verbs uses a *-(e)n* suffix.  This is the class you're referring to: *arise/arisen*, *eat/eaten*, *throw/thrown*

*Edit: I'll also note that in the second class, the vowel shift in the past form is often maintained, e.g. throw/threw/thrown, fall/fell/fallen, grow/grew/grown*.

Comment: Historically, weak verbs are those which are formed from other parts of speech within the language. If the verb is either the same as a noun or adjective ("walk") or is made from one by suffixing ("thicken"), it is very likely to be weak, and have a p.p. in -(e)d. If there is not such a noun or adjective, it is quite likely to be strong and take -(e)n. This is not an invariable rule, but it often works (though it is confounded by the recent popularity of nouns like "eats" and "sing" which didn't use to exist).

Comment: The difference didn't **start** in Old English, though it was certainly present there. It is much, much older than OE, though.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an exhaustive cataloging of verb forms you may find of use: [David Appleyard's Quest for
Regular Irregularity in English Verbs](http://www.davidappleyard.com/english/strongverbs.htm).

As Appleyard says in his intro:

> English belongs to the Germanic group of languages descended from Proto-Indo-European. One of the characteristic features of Old Germanic was its utilization of root vowel inflections to indicate changes in verb tense. While modern English makes use of a simpler suffixing system (e.g. *call-**ed**,* *phone-**d**,* etc.), verbs with irregular vowel inflections still survive for many of the oldest and most basic activities known to man, such as eating, drinking, sleeping, sitting, standing or swimming. This means that even the most elementary of students soon have to get down to the nitty-gritty of committing them to memory and I would very much like to facilitate this process.

Answer (score -2):

Well, I don't know the specifics behind this split, but it has often bothered me as well.  Given the volume of linguistic traditions that have influenced English over the centuries, I can't say that it's really surprising, though.

I'm totally guessing here, but I would venture that the -ed ending comes from some sort of evolution from the French participial form (an accented "e" for the masculine, an accented "ee" for the feminine), a holdover from the Norman conquest, whereas the -n form--again, as a total guess--comes from the Goths, Germans, or Saxons, whose languages use(d) -n for the infinitive.

I hope that makes sense and doesn't have more serious scholars jeering at me.

Comment: This is completely wrong, sorry. Both the *-n* and the *-d* are of Germanic origin, and I don't believe that French has contributed anything to English morphology.

Comment: Ah, I'm glad to know.  Thanks!  Though I'll have to defend myself and say that at least I got the German part right...and I am surprised to learn that French hasn't affected English morphology (though, of course, I defer to greater knowledge), given how much it got into our vocabulary and spelling.

Comment: I should clarify -- French hasn't contributed to our *inflectional* morphology, though of course it added quite a bit to our *derivational* morphology: all those words in *-tion* and *-age*!

Comment: @Andrew German and Germanic are two separate things. The fact that the endings are Germanic does not in any way imply that they came from German—they didn't.