# What is the origin of the "-th" suffix? What is the linguistic term for the meaning it adds to words?

Tags: meaning, etymology, suffixes, linguistics, derivational-morphology

I was teaching my young nephew some math the other day, and from discussing the typical sort of word problems he's encountering in class, I noticed that the "-th" suffix adds a distinct meaning to adjectives.  For example:

- If a ship is long, it has *length*.
- If a woman is wide, she has *width*.
- If a person is strong, he possesses *strength*.
- If what I say is true, I'm speaking *truth*.
- A lumbering panda moving slow is full of *sloth*.

Now, I've learned some linguistics from English L&U, and I'm guessing this "-th" suffix is an affix that changes adjectives into nouns.   My questions are:  What exactly is this "-th" suffix adding to the meaning? Secondly, does the "-th" originate from a separate word in Old English?  Lastly, is there something to say about the vowel shifts that seems to be occurring in some of the transformations (e.g., *strong* going to *strength*) that somehow fits in with the ablaut system of strong verbs/weak verbs, that I learned of from the excellent responses to [my previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21205/what-characterizes-english-words-that-are-conjugated-in-the-past-tense-to-end-in)?

Comment: I upvoted your question, it's interesting :) And it would be so on the Linguistics.SE too!

Comment: Very interesting question! I am agreeing more and more with the usefulness of the Linguistics site.

Comment: +1 and for the record, I think *-th* sounds much better than *-ness*. *-ness* is quite overused, especially since there's often already a word available: why *accurateness* instead of just *accuracy*? Also consider the similar *grow* → *growth*, from OE *-ð(u)*.

Comment: **1**. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-th **2**. Old English *-ðu*, *-ð*, from Proto-Germanic *-*itho*, abstract noun suffix, from PIE *-*ita* (cf. Sanskrit *-tati-*; Greek *-tet-*; Latin *-tati-*, as in *libertatem* "liberty" from *liber* "free"). http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-th **3** See also, books.google.co.in/books?id=aDhGlKL3h00C&pg=PA586

Answer (score 10):

It is, as you say, a nominalising suffix, that goes back at least to Common Germanic. 
It usually surfaces as "-th" in English, but as "-t" after a (historical) "-(g)h": "height", "weight", "sight", "flight".

The vowel alternations are mostly a matter of length (though I admit that the "-ong"/"-ength" alternation sounds a bit like IE ablaut). "Wide" in Old and Middle English was bisyllabic, with a long vowel, whereas "widþ" had one closed syllable and therefore a short vowel. Only the long vowel went waltzing round the mouth in the Great Vowel Shift.
Thinking about it, this particular alternation may go back to a time when the IE ablaut was operating, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Note that many *do* say *heighth* [haɪ(t)θ] or [haɪʔθ] for *height*, by analogy with those words that do have *th*, and since *gh* is null in modern English. I'd say *weighth* is less common, and for other *-ght* words it's hardly heard at all. People can complain all they want about it being incorrect, but hey, the only reason it was *-t* and not *-th* in the first place is gone, so why not?

Comment: I don't recall ever hearing that pronunciation, but the OED lists [haɪθ] and indeed the spelling 'highth'.

Comment: @JonPurdy The four of us were dressed in the **heighth** of fashion, ... *A Clockwork Orange* ... BTW, I say *heighth*/*highth* in the singular but *heights* in the plural :shrug:

Comment: I believe strong/strength is umlaut. We also see this in filth, from foul + th.

Answer (score 6):

In general, the suffix *-th* that creates nouns from adjectives comes from Proto-Germanic **-[iþō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/-i%C3%BE%C5%8D).*

Since this was already a suffix in Proto-Germanic, it definitely was not a separate word in Old English. In fact, it seems to descend from a Proto-Indo-European suffix, the same one that is the origin of Latin *-(i)tas* (which shows up in English borrowed words as *-(i)ty*).

The vowel shifts are not related to ablaut. There are two main causes:

- *umlaut,* or i-affection: although the original *i* in the suffix was lost by the time of Old English, it left a trace by making a preceding vowel front, changing *a* to *æ* or *e,* *o* to *e*, and *u* to *y* (which became *i* later on).
- regular shortening of long vowels before consonant clusters, and inconsistent shortening of long vowels in some cases before final single consonants

Examples:

- the Old English adjective *[strang](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/strang)*/*strong* "strong" corresponded to the noun *strængþ*(*u*)/*strengþ*(*u*) "strength," and the Old English adjective *lang*/*long* "long" corresponded to the noun *lengþ*(*u*) "length". These both show umlaut.
- In Old English, the noun corresponding to *slāw* "slow" was *[slǣwþ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sl%C3%A6w%C3%BE#Old_English),* with the expected umlaut, but the word later got remodeled to have the vowel of the adjective: *sloth*. *Sloth* has two pronunciations in modern English: it may have a shortened vowel, like *cloth* (from Old English *clāþ*) or it may not, like *oath* (from Old English *āþ*).
- The adjective *foul* is actually related to the noun *filth.* The latter shows umlaut and shortening: the words descend from Old English *fūl* and *fȳlþ.*
- the noun *width* shows shortening of the originally long vowel seen in *wide.*
- the adjective *true* corresponds to Old English *triewe*/*treowe*. (It would be more etymologically accurate if we used the spelling "trew" in modern English, but we don't because English spelling is a mess). Since the vowel in Old English (*ie* or *eo*) was front already, it didn't change in the noun *triewþ*/*treowþ* "truth".
- *breadth* has an interesting history. It does show umlaut, as can be seen from comparing it to the adjective *broad* (from Old English *brād*; the development of the vowel in modern English is [irregular](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240233/is-the-pronunciation-of-oa-in-broad-unique)). ‎But in Old English, it actually did not have the *-th* suffix: the umlaut was due to a Proto-Germanic form suffixed with something like *-j-* or *-i-*, which was lost resulting in *brǣdu* (cognate to German *[Breite](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Breite#German)*). The suffix *-th* was added to it in Middle English by analogy with words like *length* and *width.* The vowel also ended up being shortened, which is not surprising since the word ends in a consonant cluster "dth" and the Middle English vowel that corresponds to the "ea" in this word (/ɛː/) was sometimes shortened even before a single consonant (as in *bread, threat, death, deaf*).

Comment: Thank you, that was interesting. Am I right in thinking  that **troth** meaning fidelity and loyalty as in "and thereto I give thee my troth" also derives from the same root as "true"?

Comment: @BoldBen: Right; "troth" and "truth" originated as variants of the same word.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the suffix **-th** is, yes, to make adjectives into nouns. It can also change verb actions into nouns as well i.e. 'grow' into 'growth'

This suffix actually came from an Old English letter, -þ, which actually also had the same function of turning verbs and adjectives into nouns.

Comment: Idiot: Not that I'm doubting the truth of this, but it would be nice to see a corroborating reference. Such as http://www.merriam-webster.com/word/word.php?date=Apr-26-2010

Comment: Rather, the suffix has had the sound /þ/ or variants thereof since Old English, when it was usually written "þ". A linguistic element or sound cannot come from a _letter_, which is merely a way of writing down a sound.

Answer (score 2):

th as suffix  changes the verb or adjective to a noun  - no dispute there.  What does making it a noun add to the meaning?  It often seems to mean a state of:  eg  Strength - a state of strong.  Health as a state of healing, Width as a state of wide, etc.

Answer (score -6):

Th  suffix represents a continued on in the word example believeth opposed to just saying believe believeth means continue to believe,saith means continue to say

Comment: That's an entirely different _-th_, nothing to do with this question at all. It's also wrong: ‘believeth’ is simply an older form of ‘believes’, there is no difference in meaning.