# Why is "eye" pronounced so strangely?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, diphthongs

This is either a spelling or a pronunciation anomaly; I'm not sure which.  Why is "eye" pronounced as the letter "I"?

Comment: The Scottish dialect, as far as I know, say "ee"

Comment: @Thursagen: That’s generally true, though some southern varieties of the Scots language have [əi]. I believe that in Early Scots the vowel monophthongized to [e:], which was then raised to [i:] in the part of the Great Vowel Shift that took place in Scots.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Spelling of “high” vs “height”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40538)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the Etymonline [entry](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=eye):

> c.1200, from O.E. ege (Mercian), eage (W. Saxon), from P.Gmc. *augon

the *g* in Old English *ege* would be the voiced velar fricative /ɣ/.  This sound does not exist in modern English as it was palatalised to /ʝ/ and later became /j/, which we usually write with *y*.

Comment: I thought palatalization of velars was reconstructed as a pre–, not post–Old English sound change. What I remembar reading is that the reflexes of Proto-Germanic velars in palatalizing contexts were written with *g* and *c* in Old English, but pronounced as [j], [tʃ] (or when geminated, written *cg* or *gg* and *cc* and pronounced as [dːʒ], [tːʃ]).

Answer (score 10):

Both spelling and pronunciation are reasonably regular. The word is from Mercian *ēge* [e:ɣe] (West Saxon *ēage*). In Middle English the [ɣ] became [j], and the combination [e:j] developed into the diphthong [eɪ]. In later Middle English this diphthong was monophthongized to [i:], which developed into modern [aɪ] in the course of the [Great Vowel Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift). The later Middle English pronunciation can be seen in such spellings as *igh(e)*, *ihe*, and *ie*; the modern spelling, however, represents the earlier Middle English pronunciation.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the "Great Vowel Shift."  That was a very instructive link!

Comment: What other words show [e:j] > [eɪ] > [i:] > [aɪ]? Would this be like "fly" from OE *fleoge* or "die/dice" from French "de"?