# Pronunciation of the words 'height' and 'weight'

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Why is "height" an "weight" pronounced differently, when the spellings are so similar?

Is there any logical explanation or it evolved that way?

Comment: *Height* used to be written with an *ie*, and *weight* with an *i*. (And in Middle Dutch it was *oo* and *i*, and in German it's *ö* and *i*...) So yes, it evolved that way. The spelling, that is, not the pronunciation. The pronunciation has always been different, and *high* and *weigh* are pronounced differently as well, so nothing special here. More to the point, spellings never get pronounced at all — it's pronunciations that get written down, and they get written down very poorly, and not just in English but everywhere. So again, no reason to single out these two words.

Comment: The answer to this question may be helpful: [spelling of "high" vs. "height"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40538/spelling-of-high-vs-height?lq=1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as i know, in both words, "gh" would be silent when 't' comes after "gh" as per grammar rules. "ei" vowel has many accents which are understood the following examples:-
Height, reinforce, deity, weight, weird, forfeit etc.

Comment: This is not an answer, the op was actually asking about the "spelling". Check RegDwight's comment.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment RegDwigнt long ago wrote:

> *Height* used to be written with an *ie*, and *weight* with an *i*. (And in Middle Dutch it was *oo* and *i*, and in German it's *ö* and *i*...) So yes, it evolved that way. The spelling, that is, not the pronunciation. The pronunciation has always been different, and *high* and *weigh* are pronounced differently as well, so nothing special here. More to the point, spellings never get pronounced at all — it's pronunciations that get written down, and they get written down very poorly, and not just in English but everywhere. So again, no reason to single out these two words.