# Pronunciation of "lost"

Tags: pronunciation

You may think you know how to pronounce the word "lost," but Alexander Pope apparently has other ideas. One of the couplets of his poem "An Essay on Criticism" (which are all intended to rhyme) runs as follows:

> Ah ne'er so dire a thirst of glory boast, 
>   Nor in the critic let the man be lost!

So is he pronouncing lost as "loast," or boast as "bost"?

(Note: the idea that Alexandrian poetry has non-rhyming couplets expressed in some of the comments and "answers" is an absurd idea that would only occur to someone who had never seriously read or studied Pope. It is a point of fact, that ALL of Pope's couplets are meant to rhyme. Pope's couplets are known in theory as *[heroic couplets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroic_couplet)*, and it is a feature of this type of poetry, that they are composed of perfect rhymes. There is a book entitled "The Heroic Couplet" by William Bowman Piper published in 1969. If you have some question about what a perfect rhyme is, or some doubt that heroic couplets are composed of perfect rhymes, please read that book.)

Comment: All of the couplets are intended to rhyme. I think it is funny that modern "critics" are so sure of themselves that they would doubt the rhyming ability of Pope. He would have made a good satire on that, if he were alive to read it. A little knowledge is a dangerous thing...

Comment: I've also heard the technique called "close rhyme."

Comment: It's called "poetic license".  Pope even had a class A commercial license.

Comment: @EmmaDash "A little knowledge is a dangerous thing..." Or, as Alexander Pope put it, "A little **learning** is a dangerous thing."

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Having not gotten a useful answer, I researched the question at greater length myself. The Essay on Criticism has three boast-lost rhymes but no others.

In the poem Rape of the Lock, also by Pope, we get more information. In that poem he rhymes "toast" with "lost", however, he also rhymes "cross'd" with "lost":

> But see how oft Ambitious Aims are cross'd,
>   And Chiefs contend 'till all the Prize is lost!

and also "toast" with "most". In his poem, "Eloisa to Abelard," he rhymes "ghost" with "most". In his translation of Homer, we get the following equivalences:

most, cost

toss'd, coast, ghost, lost, host

Eventually, researching these equivalences further, I discovered the phenomena of the so-called [Great English Vowel Shift](https://www.prismnet.com/~dierdorf/ww-51.html). This is also [described in the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift).

What we are seeing in Pope's work is a vowel shift that has been lost. In other words, in Chaucer's time the O was short, so lost was pronounced short, but Pope pronounced it long, as "loast" according to the great vowel shift process.

Later, however, it became short again which is why we pronounce lost and crossed, not loast and crossed as "croast" as Pope pronounced them.

---

So, in summary, the answer to the question is that he is pronouncing lost as "loast" to rhyme with boast, and he was pronouncing boast the same way we pronounce it today.

Comment: The GVW shift way, way preceded Pope.

Comment: @DanBron: Some of the final stages of the GVS may have still been in progress during Pope's time. The one that I have seen mentioned is that the shift of Middle-English /ɛː/ to present-day English /iː/ may not have been complete, so, as mentioned in tautophile's answer, we see rhymes like "tea" and "obey" in Pope's poetry.

Comment: @DanBron In fact, tea continued to be pronounced "tay" by a lot of people right up through the late 19th century or even later.

Answer (score 4):

I think this question is based on a false premise: that all of Pope's couplets were meant to be exact rhymes. Some rhymes in *An Essay on Criticism* might have been exact in Pope's time, but not today: there is some discussion of this in the article "[Mother Hubbard’s Bone, Alexander Pope’s Tea](https://www.chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2013/02/07/mother-hubbards-bone-alexander-popes-tea/)", by  Allan Metcalf, and in the comments to the Language Log post "[Who would not weep, if E. B. White were he?](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1421)"

But there are also some rhymes that seem unlikely to have been exact even at the time when the poem was written.  According to "Language, and Pronunciation as shown by Rhymes", from the [Introduction](https://books.google.com/books?id=ldQ_AQAAMAAJ&pg=PR27&lpg=PR27&dq=alexander+pope++rhyme+pronunciation&source=bl&ots=Oj1j3e0gYd&sig=1yth88wsjPGrpQ7PDqWhSQXI1Pw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj854fZodbaAhVq6IMKHXSgCZ0Q6AEISTAG#v=onepage&q=alexander%20pope%20%20rhyme%20pronunciation&f=false) by E.E. Morris to Pope's *Essay on Man*:

> All Pope's rhymes cannot be defended on the ground of change in the pronunciation. 'God' could not have rhymed with 'abode,' i. 125, with 'wood,' iii. 155, and with 'road', iv. 331

(p. xxx, 1900)

In the *Essay on Criticism,* we also observe the following rhymes that seem dubious to my eyes:

- > Some ne'er advance a judgment of their **own**, / But catch the spreading notion of the t**own**

  In other places, Pope rhymes *own* with *known* and *none,* and rhymes *none* with *sun* and *upon.* If we assume that Pope pronounced each word a single way, and only used exact rhymes, then it seems we have to conclude that Pope pronounced *own, town, known, none, sun, upon* with the exact same vowel. That seems fairly unlikely, since these words did not originally all have the same vowel and they don't all have the same vowel today.
- > As shades more sweetly recommend the l**ight,**
  > So modest plainness sets off sprightly w**it**
- > Both must alike from Heav'n derive their l**ight**, / These born to judge, as well as those to wr**ite**

  If we assume that Pope used a single pronunciation for each word, and only used exact rhymes, then apparently he must have used the exact same vowel in *wit* and *write.* That seems unlikely. I suppose you could argue that Pope pronounced *light* as "lit" in one couplet and as "lite" in the other, but that also seems implausible to me.

It looks like *An Essay on Criticism* was written and published in the early 18th century. During this time period, pronunciation was not so different from present-day English pronunciation. According to "[Early Modern English: Phonology](https://www.uni-bamberg.de/fileadmin/uni/fakultaeten/split_lehrstuehle/englische_sprachwissenschaft/personen/dokumente/Schlueter/EModE_Phonology_JS_offprint.pdf)", by Alex Bergs and Laurel Brinton (2012), from *Historical Linguistics of English,*

> ME /ɔː/ as in *boat* or *no* had, by virtue of the GVS, moved to /oː/. In the late 16th and 17th centuries, it was joined by ME /ɔu/ as in *blow* or *know.* Whether the vowel resulting from this merger was monophthongal or diphthongal is debatable and without doubt varied from one dialect to another (see Section 5.1.2). From the 18th century onwards, the diphthongal realization /oʊ/ prevailed in the standard (and became Received Pronunciation /əʊ/ around 1920).

(p. 596)

> A [sound change] affected short /ɔ ~ ɒ/, which was lengthened at the same time and in the same environments as /a ~ æ/, i.e. before voiceless fricatives. Examples include *loss, off,* and *cloth.* Rather than creating a new phoneme, in the late 17th century the sound merged with /ɒː/ (which resulted from the monophthongization of ME /aʊ/ in the middle of that century). For a while, long and short versions coexisted side by side, but again the long ones were partly stigmatized. In contrast to the lengthened /a ~ æ/, short /ɒ/ was eventually restored before voiceless fricatives (except for some speakers of southern dialects).

(p. 602)

So in Pope's time, the word *boast* would have been pronounced something like [boːst] or [boʊst], and the word *lost* would have been pronounced something like [lɒst], [lɒːst], or [lɔːst]. It's unlikely that these words had exactly the same vowel, but [oː~oʊ] and [ɒː~ɔː] are fairly close and apparently this was sufficient for the words to count as a rhyme according to Pope's criteria.

tchrist's answer to the question [Was the pronunciation of “symmetry” different in the past?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216345) provides an example of Pope rhyming the word *toad* with *abroad,* which seems similar, although it's true that the retention of /ɔː/ in present-day English in the word *[broad](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240233/is-the-pronunciation-of-oa-in-broad-unique)* and its derivatives is irregular and so I guess it might be possible to argue that Pope might have used a now-lost variant pronunciation of *abroad* with [oː~oʊ].

Comment: Pope's poems are written in heroic couplets, which by definition are perfect rhymes. I have updated my question with a reference to a text book to which you can refer should you have any questions about this.

Comment: @EmmaDash: Leaving Pope aside, there have been an incredible number of English poets who wrote heroic couplets that were not perfect rhymes.For example, Nabokov's *Pale Fire,* which Wikipedia cites as an example of heoric couplets, contains at line 120: *That's Dr. Sutton's light. That's the Great Bear. A thousand years ago five minutes were...*

Comment: @PeterShor: there actually is a possible "strong form" pronunciation of *were* that is a perfect rhyme for "bear". The OED records it for British English in the form of "/wɛː/". Like the "strong" pronunciation of *was* that rhymes with "poz", I think it is nonexistent in the United States.

Answer (score -1):

It was said of Queen Anne "...whom three realms [sc. England, Scotland, and Ireland] obey, / Did sometimes counsel take--and sometimes tea."  And in truth, "tea" was normally pronounced "tay" until the mid or late 19th century.  Nowadays we pronounce it "tee".  "Divine" and "join" used to rhyme too, as we know from one of Handel's anthems: "... in songs divine, / With cherubim and seraphim harmonious join".

Comment: But what about "boast" and "lost"? It's true that some pairs of words that aren't exact rhymes today used to be exact rhymes, but I don't think it's safe to assume that this is true of all of the words that were used as rhymes in old poetry.

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

According to Wiki - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Pope Alexander moved to a small estate outside London at the age of twelve and taught himself for five years before returning to London. This may have given him a local dialect that Londoners did not have, but understood.

**@sumelic** As for, "False eloquence, like the prismatic glass, / Its gaudy colours spreads on ev'ry place." The word *glace* means 'finished with a gloss.'^ and it would perfectly well in this stanza. Better than the 'glass' it was substituted for.

Comment: I'm doubtful that the word "glass" here is a mistaken transcription of "glace", but I removed that part of my answer because I found a source that suggests that in fact Pope may have pronounced "-ace" words from French with the sound of "-ass".

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Comment: The word *glacé*, borrowed from French, means "finished with a gloss"
, rhymes with *assay*, and according to the dictionary, didn't enter the English language until over a century after Pope died. Would Pope have misspelled *glacé* as *glass*, and pronounced it to rhyme with *place*? I doubt it.

Comment: Wow. - 2 points for being accurate and referential. Maybe I should have made it an opinion. Some of the contributors here only posted posited responses, and no points against them.

Comment: You think this "may have given him ..." isn't a "posited response"?

Comment: @Peter Shor LOL. It at least was conjoined with a reference for further information on Pope's development and history. Writing, **as comment on an answer,** "I'm doubtful the word "glass " here is a mistaken transcription of "glace", leads you where as a reader?